# iframe not palying the video

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I've used iframe in my html page which contains the base video like this

```
<iframe id="iframe" poster="this.png" src="https://streamadblocker.com/e/Video_ID" width="750" height="400" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

and i have other parts of the video as well which I have managed to do like this

```
<a class="alnk" data-src="https://streamadblocker.com/e/Video_ID">Part 2</a>
```

but i have not created the links like this one by one additionally i've used js to read the file which contains all the links or src of the video and create the a tag inside a div something like this

```
 const linkContainer = document.querySelector(".prtd");

fetch('urls.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const urls = data.split('\n').filter(Boolean);
    const numVideos = urls.length;

    for (let i = 1; i <= numVideos; i++) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.className = "alnk";
      link.setAttribute("data-src", urls[i]);
      link.textContent = `Part ${i + 1}`;
      linkContainer.appendChild(link);
    }
  });
```

The main thing comes here I Now have a problem with the iframe the thing that I did is suppose I have Part 2 and 3 and 4 links of the video are there which contains data-src of the video in anchor tag which has class of ".alnk" and after clicking the Part 2 the iframe which Previoiusly had the base video src should repalce with the src in which part I click. In short when I click the Part 3 it should play the Part 3 in the iframe replacing the base Video. To achieve that i've tried this code of JS

```
const videoPlayer = document.getElementById("iframe");
const partLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".alnk");

partLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const src = this.getAttribute("data-src");
    videoPlayer.setAttribute("src", src);
    videoPlayer.play();
  });
});
```

After adding this code it does not play the video on iframe additionally in the browser console it showed this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isActive')
> at Object._userActivationHandler

Full Js code

```
const linkContainer = document.querySelector(".prtd");

fetch('urls.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const urls = data.split('\n').filter(Boolean);
    const numVideos = urls.length;

    for (let i = 1; i < numVideos; i++) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.className = "alnk";
      link.setAttribute("data-src", urls[i]);
      link.textContent = `Part ${i + 1}`;
      linkContainer.appendChild(link);
    }
  });

const videoPlayer = document.getElementById("iframe");
const partLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".alnk");

partLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const src = this.getAttribute("data-src");
    videoPlayer.setAttribute("src", src);
    videoPlayer.play();
  });
});

const mrElement = document.getElementById("mr");
const downloadOptions = document.getElementById("download-options");
downloadOptions.style.display = "none";

$("#mr").click(function () {
  $(".trant").toggleClass("trant-active");
});

mrElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (downloadOptions.style.display === "none") {
    downloadOptions.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    downloadOptions.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Also I am new to JS I don't know errors and things that much
If any one Could help I would be very Thankful
Thank You!

Comment: Browsers block autoplaying videos until a page has been interacted with, so _by definition_ your video won't play until the user has _at least_ click into it, or you make it autoplay in a muted state. People abused immediate autoplay so hard that browser makers agreed to simply ban the use.

Comment: using iframe it does not play but using video  element it does but using video element is  not suitable as it does not load the video